# Android finish current activity and start parent activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a little question which is bothering me. How can I finish activity C and start it's parent. But the tricky part is that I can start activity C from 20 other activites. The idea is to open the right one when i call finish on C. And the other thing is that I have `tabhost` , which childs opens activity C.

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: activity c has tabhost in it or some mainactivity contains the tabhost and from those tab activities activity c you are calling !!

Comment: you may extend your activity with ActivityGroup (A screen that contains and runs multiple embedded activities.) where you will be able to finish activity C and clear the list of all predecendant activities to let your initial activity to be restarted again. If it is tabhost, look for TabGroupActivity class example

Comment: the second one, activity C is called by activities which are in tabhost.

Comment: Yes Mocialov Boris is correct for cases like tabhost and activities inside it , one should go for activitygroup.

Comment: Actually I'm already using activitygroup in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply did something like this :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 finish();
```

This did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

in your activity C save the following variable:

```
Class parent = ParentActivityClass.class;
```

override:

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    //create an intent like
    Intent i = new Intent(this, parent);
    startActivity(i);
    //add extras to intent if needed
    this.finish();
}
```

please note that this might create a NEW parent activity. it is up to you handle this situation if this might create problems.

An alternate solution is to finish each other child activity when you launch a new activity. This will assure that on your stack you will have always the parent below the child activity.

Answer (score 1):

Depend on your activity stack if your current exactly on top of the parent activity you can just finish current actvity and it will go to previous activity. If you want to clear all activity stack and start over new activity try

```
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, activity.class);
             intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
            startActivity(intent1);
```

which clear your stack and start over new if you have stack of activity over parent want to finish all use this and start over parent again.

Comment: i want to return to the previous activity and I forget to mention that I want to clear the history, but what should i put instead of `activity.class`  ?

Comment: the activityname you want to redirect as a class

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Task and Backstack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html), [Implementing Temporal](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) and [Ancestral Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

There are more specific explanations. Hope this help